# Logging boost::exception while avoiding file/line/function and the nagging

Tags: c++, boost, exception

In my in-house logging library, I am trying to change the custom exception class to derive from boost::exception instead of std::exception. I am doing this so that I can use a single catch block for both boost exceptions and my application exceptions. But I am running into an issue while logging it.

While logging the exception using boost::diagnostic_information(), I get the whole 9 yards about the throw location. This information is redundant for me since my custom class already collects and uses this info in a way I want. I don't want to print source code file/line/function info in the log.

If I define BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE or don't use BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION, it prints "**Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)**" every time I log the exception.

But how do I escape this nagging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I think I found the answer myself. First of all, I don't have to derive my class from boost::exception, I can still continue to derive from std::exception. However, I should throw my std::exception derived class using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION. So it becomes boost::exception as it takes off. :-)

In between, I can add more info if required by catching and rethrowing.

```
  typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_errmsg, std::string> exceptionInfo; 

  catch (boost::exception &e) 
  { 
    e << exceptionInfo("some more exception data"); 
    throw; 
  }
```

And then I can finally catch it and print it this way:

```
catch (boost::exception &e) 
{ 
    std::exception const * se = dynamic_cast<std::exception const *>(&e);
    if(se)
    {
        // will enter here only for my application exception and not for pure boost exception
        std::cout << "STD: " << se->what();
    }
    std::cout << " BOOST: " << *boost::get_error_info<exceptionInfo>(e);        }
}
```

This way I will get both the what() string from std::exception and the error message from boost::exception. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Do not you want to use exception::what() instead of boost::diagnostic_information()?

Comment: There is no what() function in boost:exception.